# Write a file from a command-line piped output?

Tags: vb.net, output, pipe

So, it's been years since I've had to code in VB.NET and I'm *really* rusty. I'm trying to write the output of bcedit.exe to a file that I plan to read from later. This is on an x64 system and I need to run the command as admin. Works fine with the exception of the file not being written.

**Here's what I have so far**:

```
Private Sub BCDEdit(strWhich As String)' This sub runs the Windows bcdedit program, with a paramater, edit the boot.ini file.

    Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim pStartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

    pStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()

    With pStartInfo
        .FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() & "\bcdedit.exe"
        .Verb = "runas"
        .Arguments = strWhich
        .WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        .UseShellExecute = True
    End With

    p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pStartInfo)

    p.WaitForExit()

End Sub
```

**And I call the sub with**:

```
BCDEdit("> " & Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") & "\DUMP.tmp".ToString())
```

Seems like half the struggle has to do with the value of `.UseShellExecute`, I need it set to `True` in order for the command prompt to stay hidden, however, if I set it to `False` I can somewhat use `.RedirectStandardOutput` and read it to memory instead (although I still haven't got the actual piping of the output to work that way yet either).

Doing a `bcdedit > C:\temp\dump.txt` from an elevated command prompt works fine, so something's getting lost in the translation.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you checked the value of the string in debug to see that you're getting the value you think you are?  Sometimes environment variables can have the last \ already added.

Comment: Yep, I set a breakpoint on the p = system.(etc.) line and checked; according to the values everything looks correct.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the paths during debug: http://screencast.com/t/NWnks07j6QX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the redirection modifier isn't recognized as an argument.  You will probably have to redirect the output manually by redirecting the standard output stream capturing it and outputting it to the file.

Also it appears you have it backwards, `UseShellExecute` should be false to use `System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`.  According to [ProcessWindowStyle Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here's a simple example:

```
    Dim newprocess As New Process()
    With newprocess.StartInfo
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString() & "\bcdedit.exe"
        .Verb = "runas"
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
    End With
    'Change the False to True to append instead of overwrite
    Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") & "\DUMP.tmp", False)
    newprocess.Start()
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = newprocess.StandardOutput
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine)
    End While
    sw.Close()
    sr.Close()
```

Not sure why 'runas' doesn't work for that app, but I did some more thinking on it and found a solution that will work:

```
    Dim newprocess As New Process()
    With newprocess.StartInfo
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .Verb = "runas"
        .FileName = "cmd"
        .Arguments = "/c bcdedit > " & Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") & "\DUMP.tmp"
        .UseShellExecute = True
    End With
    newprocess.Start()
```

Basically this uses the command processer in administrator mode to run bcdedit with the standard output modifier('>').

Comment: Well, that's interesting, in the actual program setting it to True doesn't show the window while setting it to false does. Regarding the first part: Do you have a code sample to get me started?

Comment: The redirect pipe `|` is handled by the command interpreter: `cmd.exe`.  As you are not invoking `cmd.exe` here you don't get that functionality.

Comment: Thanks, while this does solve the issue of writing the file, it still doesn't work properly in my case since I need to write the info of a program that I need to run with admin rights. Using this code it just outputs a file with the same text you would see when trying to run bcedit.exe in a a non-elevated command prompt, basically because UseShellExecute is set to False, which means the actual OS shell isn't starting the process. I guess it's just a Windows glitch to make life for us devs harder, lol.

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to find some other way to accomplish this, instead of writing a file.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein found a solution for you

Comment: @tinstaafl I appreciate all the help. =) This update does write the file with the correct info, but now I'm stuck with the issue of the command window flashing instead of staying hidden, lol. That damn `UseShellExecute`! lmao.

Comment: @tinstaafl If no one gives a better solution soon I'll mark yours as Accepted Answer, and just live with the flashing command window.